# Gstreamer Extract Audio From m3u8 Video Stream

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to extract the audio from a HLS m3u8 live video stream into either FLAC, PCM, or OGG-OPUS.  I've tried several options.  They all create the file on my desktop but when I play the file, no audio is recorded.

**Convert to FLAC**

`gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=[m3u8 URL] ! hlsdemux ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! flacenc ! filesink location=audio.flac`

**Convert to PCM**

`gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=[m3u8 URL] ! hlsdemux ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,format=S32BE,channels=1,rate=48000 ! filesink location=audio.pcm`

**Convert to OGG-OPUS**

`gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=[m3u8 URL] ! hlsdemux ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! opusenc ! filesink location=audio.ogg`

**Information about the m3u8 HLS stream from gst-discoverer-1.0**

```
Properties:
  Duration: 99:99:99.999999999
  Seekable: no
  Live: no
  container: application/x-hls
    container: MPEG-2 Transport Stream
      audio: MPEG-4 AAC
        Stream ID: 722f60699ac437d8b42b2325b9497eb8707874802bf34a0185ca68ebfd95dd38/src_0:1/00000101
        Language: <unknown>
        Channels: 2 (front-left, front-right)
        Sample rate: 48000
        Depth: 32
        Bitrate: 0
        Max bitrate: 0
      video: H.264 (Main Profile)
        Stream ID: 722f60699ac437d8b42b2325b9497eb8707874802bf34a0185ca68ebfd95dd38/src_0:1/00000100
        Width: 768
        Height: 432
        Depth: 24
        Frame rate: 30000/1001
        Pixel aspect ratio: 1/1
        Interlaced: false
        Bitrate: 0
        Max bitrate: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and posted the solution on GitHub:

[GStreamer Example on GitHub](https://github.com/marc-parillo/gstreamer-transcribe)

This Node.js example will take a live m3u8 stream, use GStreamer to extract the audio, save it to a FLAC audio file, and send to AWS Transcribe all in real-time.  (Some code copied from other examples on-line and combined into one working example.)